# Converting ArrayList<String> object to integer in Java

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I am trying to read a combination of Strings and ints into an ArrayList from a txt file. I know the issue has something to do with the conversion of the ArrayList String object to Integer, but I have no Idea how to fix it. I am initializing the first two indexes of the arraylist to the instance variables "name" and "creationDate". the purpose of the program is an mp3 player with the playlist name, creation date, and song title, artist, and length.   Please help!!

```
    public void readPlaylist(String path) {

    String token = "";
    ArrayList<String> temps = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File(path)).useDelimiter("\n");

        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            token = inputFile.next();
            temps.add(token);

        }
        inputFile.close();

    } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Could not open the input file");

    }

    this.name = (String) temps.get(0);
    this.creationDate = (String) temps.get(1);
    for (int i = 2; i < temps.size() -2; i+=3) {
        String title = (String) temps.get(i);
        String artist = (String) temps.get(i + 1);
        int duration;
        duration = parseInt((String) temps.get(i+2));
        System.out.println(temps.get(i+2));
        Song song = new Song(title,artist,duration);
        list.add(song);

    }

}
```

Here is the txt file that im reading from:

```
KB Jams
09/01/2013
Repect
Aritha Franklin
182
Since I Fell for You
Jimmy Smith
256
Green Onions
Booker T. & the MG's
174
One Nation Under the Groove (Instrumental)
Parliament Funkadelic
347
I'd Rather Be With You
Bootsy Collins
294
Alpha and Omega
Israel & New Breed
351
Nobody Greater
VaShawn Mitchell
397
```

Comment: You don't need to cast `temps.get`. They are already strings. And you should be using `Integer.parseInt` unless `parseInt` is a method you defined and aren't showing in your question

Comment: “I know the issue has something to do with the conversion of the ArrayList String object to Integer, but I have no Idea how to fix it.”  Fix what?  What is “the issue”?  What behavior are you expecting, and what is happening instead?

Comment: Which exception/error are you getting?

Comment: here are the exceptions:                                                                          at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)

Comment: I imported `import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt` so that I can just use `parseInt` @cricket . And the I accidentally left the (String) cast when i posted the code. Removing the cast has no effect... @VGR, I am trying to take an integer value from the arraylist of Strings and cast it to int so i can pass it to the Song class constructor. However I throw a lot of exceptions regarding the `parseInt`

Comment: If your strings contain anything other than a number, such as a single space, you'll get a NumberFormatException, like you see. You can `trim` the String to see if they helps. Also, printing the value you are trying to parse first will help you debug the problem

Comment: P.S. thanks for your quick responses

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the full error message? It should tell you what you are trying to parse

Comment: Okayyyy, the trim method actually solved the problem! Thank you so much! @cricket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string contains anything other than a numerical value, such as a space, you'll get your NumberFormatException error.

That error should tell you what you are trying to parse.

The reason you wouldn't see spaces or newlines using a print statement is because it's just whitespace.

You can trim the String to get rid of excess whitespace surrounding your number

```
parseInt(temps.get(i+2).trim())
```